# Does the FBCustomUILoginSample sample app have special default permissions?

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to integrate the latest Facebook IOS sdk in my app. When I run their `FBCustomUILoginSample` this is what I get for the `FBSession`

```
(lldb) po FBSession.activeSession
<FBSession: 0x9a70780, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x58338, appID: 625893600789351, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x9ca9be0>, expirationDate: 2014-07-05 01:12:37 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-06 20:55:42 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
"public_profile",
email,
"user_birthday",
"user_location",
"user_friends"
)>
```

but when I run the same code in my own app, I get this as the `FBSession.activeSession`

```
(lldb) po FBSession.activeSession
<FBSession: 0xd0a3230, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x34cfa0, appID:    312345678912341, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xb843ca0>, expirationDate: 2014-07-04 23:36:57 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-06 21:12:15 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    "public_profile",
    "user_friends"
)>
```

Do the sample apps have special defaults? Is there something I need to set on the FB App console? From what I can gather, I'm doing exactly what the sample app is doing (code below). Why are my permissions different?:

```
   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

       // Retrieve the app delegate
       AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
       [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Which permissions are you asking for? in the latest SDK you can only ask for the following permissions without submitting your Facebook app for review: public_profile, email, and user_friends

More info here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading